# Command logging for chroot ssh users

Tags: linux, ssh, logging, chroot

I have a ubuntu server that allows users access via ssh.
When they log in they are contained to their chroot directory.

I'm looking for a way to log commands used by the users. I've tried using snoopy but it doesn't log commands for users in chroot.

It there any possible solution for this ? The only similar resources I've found have been for sftp. Would greatly appreciate any advice, thanks.

Comment: did you already thinked about monitoring   `.bash_history`?

Comment: Yeah I considered it, however as it would be possible for the user to clear the history I don't think it is viable.